# Javascript function declaration / definition parameters / arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm slowly, but surely learning AngularJS, but have a quick query.

Why is it I can't declare namespaced or object.property syntax in the function parameter list like so:

```
var myFunc = function(vm.startDate, vm.endDate) {
```

...
...

Comment: You declare function arguments inside parenthis `function(argName1, argName2)` and `vm.startDate` is not valid identifier because you can't have dots in it.

Comment: if variables are scoped (`this.startDate` / `$scope.startDate` / `vm.startDate`) then you don't even need to pass them as parameters, they can be accessed within the scope of the controller

Answer (score 0):

Functions take arguments. When you define a function, you're saying 'These are the pieces of data I want to work with' and those arguments are then instanciated as local, scoped values.

If you wanted to pass scoped variables, you can do that by using a parametrized object in your call:

```
var myFunc = function(vm) 
{ 
   console.log(vm.startDate, vm.endDate); 
};

myFunc({startDate: 'today', endDate: 'tomorrow'});
```

In this case you're creating an object and you pass it to the function. Make sure to check potentially missing members before using them in your code, for example via

```
console.assert(vm.hasOwnProperty('startDate'), 'VM is missing start date!');
```

Comment: Thanks.   "Parameterized Object" was the term I obviously needed to Google!